# How to use PayPal Periodic Recurring Payments

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I checked through lots of the documentation, and need to confirm that I have come to the right conclusion.

When doing Recurring Payments, I can only do them for up to 12 months??

Meaning 52 weekly payments or 12 monthly payments??

How do you handle recurring payments that you want to go beyond this, do you send a request to the original payee?

Thanks very much in advance,

V

Comment: What technology are you talking about?  PayPal?

Comment: Yes I am asking about PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what doc you are reading that gives you this impression (maybe you could share a specific reference?) but to my knowledge (and I was involved in these products for years @ PayPal) NO this is not a limitation of any of PayPal's recurring payments products.

Comment: I was looking at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Perhaps I have mixed up billing frequency, period and cycle??
If billing cycle is 0 (unlimited) payments keep going 'forever'?

Comment: Correct. E.g. Period='Years', frequency=1, cycle=0 means repeat the payment each 1 year (indefinitely). Period='week', frequency='3', cycle=0 means repeat the payment every 3 weeks (indefinitely). Period='month', frequency=1,cycle=12 means repeat the payment every month for 12 months, then stop.